# Is there anything that links AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment to the nested stack it creates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I can deploy an EB environment via CloudFormation with AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment and AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion in the same template

That's great but if the beanstalk app *deployment* fails CloudFormation doesn't fail- the stack/environment is usually created successfully. So CloudFormation deploys successfully, the Beanstalk app version deploy fails, Beanstalk rolls back to the previous version, and returns to a healthy state and the only way I know it failed is to view the console or doing something wonky like try to check the current app version after the deployment.

The nested stack AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment creates however *does* seem to fail if the app version deployment fails, but I can find no way of linking the two which is very annoying.

I need to programmatically identify the nested stack AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment creates so after CloudFormation finishes and can check the status of that nested stack to see if the Beanstalk deploy was actually successful

### Edit

At least they are tagged with the environment name. I really don't love this but it seems to work, curious about better options though:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[?Tags[?Key == `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` && Value == `myenvname`]].{StackName: StackName}' --output text
```

Answer (score 0):

Its technically not a nested stack, but a fully independent stack from `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment`.

Nevertheless, one way to get the stack name, would be through [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CFN.

In the CFN you would have a lambda which would use [describe-environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environments.html) using your environment, get the EB stack name, and return it to your stack for further processing.

One of the outcomes of the query is `EnvironmentId`. For example

```
"EnvironmentId": "e-ctpmqpqwjm"
```

The stack that EB produces has name in the format:

```
awseb-<EnvironmentId>-stack
```

Sadly, I can't find any reference for this. This is based on **my own observations**. Thus, if you would choose to explore this option, you would have to verify if the naming convention is same for you.

Comment: if thats really the only way then filtering stacks by `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` tag is a million times better. You could probably deploy envs with your own tag and search on that too

Comment: @red888 Whether its better is subjective. Tags can be modified, or deleted by anyone who has access to aws console leading to errors. But you can't just delete `EnvironmentId` or change it to whatever you want, making it more resilient. You still have to use custom resource if you want to keep everything under control of CFN, even if using tags.